# Where is the union() method on the Spark DataFrame class?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am using the Java connector for Spark and would like to union two DataFrames but bizarrely the DataFrame class has only unionAll? Is this intentional and is there a way to union two DataFrames without duplicates?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is this intentional

If think it is safe to assume that it is intentional. Other union operators like `RDD.union` and `DataSet.union` will keep duplicates as well.

If you think about it make sense. While operation equivalent to `UNION ALL` is just a logical operation which requires no data access or network traffic finding distinct elements requires shuffle and because of that can be quite expensive.

> is there a way to union two DataFrames without duplicates?

```
df1.unionAll(df2).distinct()
```